# index+1 to with_index without going off index

Tags: ruby

This is my very round-about way to prevent +1 to the last index in the array. What's the best practice to achieve this in ruby? Thanks in advance.

```
  array.each.with_index do |x, index|
    unless index+1 == array.length
      if x + array[index+1] == n
        ...
```

Comment: Obviously that should be `array[0..-2]` since `[_..-1]` is from beginning to end, or `array[_...-1]` (non-inclusive).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
array[0..-2].each.with_index do |x, index|
      if x + array[index+1] == n
        ...
```

Comment: Because he don't want to get to the last index in the array right?

Comment: Oh, doh; my bad. Wasn't paying attention to my own comment. I left off a period, and misread yours. Yay.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a *range* to do what you want. Something like:

```
array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
array[0...-1].each do |x|
    print x
end
# => 0123
```

`-1` refers to the last element, and using 3 dots `...` means you're taking all the elements from the first to the last **exclusively**. 2 dots would also include the last one.

Bonus tip: in ruby, you'll be able to get away most of the times by using `each` instead of `each_with_index`, by culling/modifying the array beforehand.